# How to do comparison like greater than or less than with "Safe Casts"

Tags: android, kotlin

In Kotlin:
getting value using `get` without `?` not acceptable. But with `?` comparison not acceptable. I did search about it but couldn't find solution.

Code example

```
var doc = document.getData();
var v = doc?.get("curr_version");

if(v > BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE){

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an explicit null check:

```
if (v != null && v > BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use elvis operator to return a default value if `v` is null like :

```
if (v ?: 0 > BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE)
```

or use `?.let { }` to be sure that v is not null like :

```
v?.let {
    if (it > BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE) {

    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like the programming style with higher-order functions, I'd recommend this idiom for your code:

```
document.getData()
        ?.get("curr_version")
        ?.takeIf { it > BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE }
        ?.also {
           ...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I will answear to)

```
val doc = document.getData()
doc?.let{
    if(it.get("curr_version") > BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE){
        //TODO
    }
}?:run { 
    //TODO If null
}
```